# Float или position?

Tags: html, css

Имеется разметка:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Как правильно сверстать двухколоночную структуру?
1-ый вариант:

```
.container {overflow:hidden;}
.sidebar {float:left;width: 200px;}
.content {float:right;width:800px;}
```

2-ой вариант

```
.container {position:relative;padding-left:200px;width:1000px;}
.sidebar {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:200px;}
.content {}
```

Мне нравится решение под номером два, оно более надежно так как блоки не плывут при масштабировании, но в чем их принципиальное отличие, и что правильнее?

Comment: Во втором случае, когда высота сайдбара окажется больше высоты экрана и высоты контента, станет плохо

Comment: @andreymal, почему? Там же absolute, а не fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}
.sidebar {}
.content {}
```

И просто наполняйте контентом